# Get Mutex protected value in Coroutine from none-coroutine threads without mpsc?

Tags: rust, mutex, coroutine

How to get Mutex protected value in Coroutine from none-coroutine threads in Rust. Without using mpsc.

```
struct S1 {
    value: Arc<tokio::sync::Mutex<f64>>,
}

impl S1 {
    fn start(&self) {
        let v = self.value.clone();
        RT.spawn(async move {
            loop {
                let lk = v.lock().await;
                *lk += 1.0;
                drop(lk);
                // sleep 1s
            }
        });
        
        //sleep 5s
        let lk = self.value.lock() //`start` is not an async function, so you can't call self.value.lock().await here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code not work? Why you don't want to use mpsc? Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`tokio::sync::Mutex::blocking_lock()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.blocking_lock) for locking a tokio mutex outside of async context.

```rust
    fn start(&self) {
        let v = self.value.clone();
        RT.spawn(async move {
            loop {
                let lk = v.lock().await;
                *lk += 1.0;
                drop(lk);
                // sleep 1s
            }
        });
        
        // sleep 5s
        let lk = self.value.blocking_lock();
        // ...
    }
```

However note that [you should prefer `std::sync::Mutex` as long as you don't need to hold the lock across `.await` points](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html#which-kind-of-mutex-should-you-use).